# multiprocessing.Pool with maxtasksperchild produces equal PIDs

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pid

I need to run a function in a process, which is completely isolated from all other memory, several times. I would like to use `multiprocessing` for that (since I need to serialize a complex output coming from the functions). I set the `start_method` to `'spawn'` and use a pool with  `maxtasksperchild=1`. I would expect to get a different process for each task, and therefore see a different PID:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

def f(x):
    print("PID: %d" % os.getpid())
    time.sleep(x)
    complex_obj = 5 #more complex axtually
    return complex_obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1)
    pool.map(f, [5]*30)
    pool.close()
```

However the output I get is:

```
$ python untitled1.py 
PID: 30010
PID: 30009
PID: 30012
PID: 30011
PID: 30010
PID: 30009
PID: 30012
PID: 30011
PID: 30018
PID: 30017
PID: 30019
PID: 30020
PID: 30018
PID: 30019
PID: 30017
PID: 30020
...
```

So the processes are not being respawned after every task. Is there an automatic way of getting a new PID each time (ie without starting a new pool for each set of processes)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to also specify `chunksize=1` in the call to `pool.map`. Otherwise, multiple items in your iterable get bundled together into one "task" from the perception of the worker processes:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

def f(x):
    print("PID: %d" % os.getpid())
    time.sleep(x)
    complex_obj = 5 #more complex axtually
    return complex_obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1)
    pool.map(f, [5]*30, chunksize=1)
    pool.close()
```

Output doesn't have repeated PIDs now:

```
PID: 4912
PID: 4913
PID: 4914
PID: 4915
PID: 4938
PID: 4937
PID: 4940
PID: 4939
PID: 4966
PID: 4965
PID: 4970
PID: 4971
PID: 4991
PID: 4990
PID: 4992
PID: 4993
PID: 5013
PID: 5014
PID: 5012
```

Comment: But was not chunksize=1 by default? why there is need for explicitly specifying chunksize=1 ?

Comment: @burcak No, chunksize is not set to 1 by default. It is calculated like this by default `chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)`.

Comment: I wrote so becasue I saw ``def imap_unordered(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):`` in pool.py from anaconda3/lib/multiprocessing/pool.py

Comment: chunksize is 1 by default for `imap`, but not for `map`, which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 3):

observe that using `chunksize=1` in a `Pool` map will do the pool wait for a complete round of process to finish to start a new one.

```
with Pool(3, maxtasksperchild=1) as p:
    p.map(do_job, args_list, chunksize=1)
```

For example, above the pool will wait until all the first 3 process (eg `1000,1001,1002`) finish to then start the new round(`1003,1004,1005`)