# The same process in the process pool will be executed multiple times

Tags: python

I wrote a python script to test the multi-process pool and use apply_async to call the class method. But why does the same process (same pid) output multiple times in the output?

OS: centos-7.4
PYTHON: python-2.7

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

class New(object):
        def __init__(self):
                self.pid = os.getpid()

        def gen(self, num):
                pid = os.getpid()
                print 'NEW PROCESS PID IS {}'.format(pid)
                return (pid, num)

        def log(self, pid):
                print 'START WRITE {} INTO FILE'.format(pid[0])
                with open('log', 'a') as f:
                        f.write('CURRENT PROCESS IS {} <--> NUM IS {}\n'.format(pid[0], pid[1]))
        def start(self):
                print 'CREATE MAIN PROCESS {}'.format(self.pid)
                self.pool = Pool()
                num = 0
                while True:
                        narg = num
                        self.pool.apply_async(self, args=(narg,), callback=self.log)
                        num += 1
                        time.sleep(2)
                self.pool.close()
                self.pool.join()
        def __call__(self, num):
                return self.gen(num)

        def __getstate__(self):
                self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
                del self_dict['pool']
                return self_dict

        def __setstate__(self, state):
                self.__dict__.update(state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        new = New()
        new.start()
```

The following is the result of the script print, the same process id output twice，The specific code is below。
eg:

```
NEW PROCESS PID IS 14459
START WRITE 14459 INTO FILE
NEW PROCESS PID IS 14459
START WRITE 14459 INTO FILE
```

callback of apply_async will write some lines into file. 
The output at the same time is as follows
eg:

```
CURRENT PROCESS IS 14459 <--> NUM IS 29
CURRENT PROCESS IS 14459 <--> NUM IS 30
```

I just want to get one print and write for one process.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing is expected. The point of using a `multiprocessing.Pool()` is to distribute the work over a pool of workers (i.e., processes). See [multiprocessing.Pool with maxtasksperchild produces equal PIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943161/multiprocessing-pool-with-maxtasksperchild-produces-equal-pids) for one way to achieve what you want. But honestly, it seems to me you should just be using `multiprocessing.Process()` if you want to spawn a new process for each iteration of the inner loop.