# why the output shows that one process has performed multiple tasks

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
def send_request(data):


    lock.acquire()
    print(data,' ',os.getpid())
    lock.release()

def init(l):
    global lock
    lock = l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_list = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8, initializer=init, initargs=(lock,),maxtasksperchild=1)
    pool.map(send_request, range(10000))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Part of the output of the program is as follows

```
9995   15824
9996   15824
9997   15824
9998   15824
9999   15824
```

According to the setting of maxtasksperchild, it should be that each process executes only one task, why the output shows that one process has performed multiple tasks.

However，when I change the statement from `pool.map(send_request, range(10000))` to `pool.map(send_request, range(9))`, the output shows that the maxtasksperchild setting is normal.

```
0   11776
1   5424
2   10984
3   15848
4   11000
5   16728
6   4480
7   12016

8   12936
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiprocessing.Pool with maxtasksperchild produces equal PIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943161/multiprocessing-pool-with-maxtasksperchild-produces-equal-pids)

Answer (score 2):

you'll find an equivalent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943161/multiprocessing-pool-with-maxtasksperchild-produces-equal-pids)

In a nutshell, a multiprocessing `task` is a set of multiple input arguments that are send together (in batches of size `chunksize`) for performance reasons. Thus a worker will execute at most `maxtaskperchild * chunksize` function calls.

The chunk size can specified in the `pool.map` call with:

```py
pool.map(send_request, range(1000), chunksize=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks expected behavior to me. According to the reference documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), function `Pool.map()`

> chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the
>   process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks
>   can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

This clearly allows the option to invoke `send_request` multiple times with different arguments for the same process. Passing `chunksize=1` should fix that issue.